# isEven in another method

Tags: java

Something is very wrong here...

```
public class evenness {

    public static Boolean isEven (Integer i) {

        return (i % 2) == 0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (isEven(Integer i)) { //something wrong on this line.
            System.out.print("YAY!");
        }


    }

}
```

Please help me sort it out!

Comment: @John i is even if i % 2 = 0
so what do you mean?

Comment: John: did you skip classes on basic arithmetics, or are you just trolling?

Comment: Then, please, don't just go and repeat things that "you just heard somewhere"... there's way too much disinformation everywhere nowadays that repeating things gets dangerous.

Comment: @Bruno:  Neither.  This was the argument I remembered, and it was incorrect -- hence why I deleted my comments:  http://ask.metafilter.com/8444/Is-Zero-odd-or-even

Comment: @maclunian:  Sorry for the distraction. I was incorrect.

Comment: Jesus! There's no need to skip arithmetics classes to have this misconception... even arithmetics teachers don't know arithmetics! "several sections of prospective elementary school teachers were given a true-or-false test including the item 'Zero is an even number.' They found it to be a 'tricky question', and about two thirds answered 'False'". (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero#Teachers.27_knowledge)

Comment: @maclunian I'd suggest you accept an answer if one has been helpful to you.

Answer (score 7):

You are supposed to give an Integer argument to the function `isEven`, for example `3` or `125`.

I'm pretty sure that your IDE is telling you that it can't find the variable Integer. So you need to give a variable. The argument type is only required in the method definition.

For example:

```
int number = 4;
if(isEven(number)){
    ...
}
```

or more directly

```
if(isEven(4)){
    ...
}
```

Comment: `if (isEven(3)) {...` or `if (isEven(42)) {...`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (isEven(Integer i)) {
```

to something like

```
int i = 5;
if (isEven(i)) {
```

or

```
if (isEven(5)) {
```

You need to pass an integer to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide an argument where you call your method in main();

```
public class evenness {

public static Boolean isEven (Integer i) {

    return (i % 2) == 0;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (isEven(36)) { //something wrong on this line.
        System.out.print("YAY!");
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Following Java coding convention by changing the class name to `Evenness`.

```
public class Evenness
```

The method `isEven(...)` should accept `int` and return `boolean`.  Both are primitive data types. This will make the program runs faster than using their wrappers. A wrapper is a reference type (object) that wraps a primitive type. For example, `Integer` wraps `int` and `Boolean` wraps `boolean`.

```
    public static boolean isEven (int i) {
```

Send an argument to `isEven(...)`

```
        if (isEven(2)) { // this line is now OK.
```